# Differential Equation Prediction Model for Future Revenue

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, finance, differential-equations

I'm trying to predict time series with the physical model of the process. Simple heuristic model for the predicting the company's future revenue.

The hypothesis for the model are:

- The company's revenue growth is exponential.
- Future growth depends on the past growth.
- Global market condition can impact company's growth.

I'm trying to encode it in form of differential equation:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
r_{t+1}=v_{t+1}r_{t} \\ 
v_{t+1}=v_{t}a_{t+1} \\
v_{t0} = someconstant \\
a_{t} = knownforanyt
\end{array}
$$

Where $r$ - revenue, $v$ - velocity, $a$ - acceleration (known for any t even in the future), $t$ - discrete time interval, month by month.

1) **Where can I learn more about such approach?** How it's called, especially in finance?

2) And, one issue I'm currently have - **how to deal with the negative revenue**? I'm currently calculating $v_{t0}$ as an average monthly growth for last 4 years. The problem is - when company revenue changes from positive to negative (net revenue could be negative even if gross revenue is positive) - **there's no way to calculate the average monthly growth**.

In `2000-12 revenue 1mUSD`, in `2001-12 revenue -1mUSD`, no way to calculate average monthly growth, the equation $({-1 / 1})^{1/12}$ doesn't make sense. How to deal with that? Is the underlying differential equation model wrong? Or maybe I'm using it wrongly - I'm currently fitting it by hands - by calculating the average monthly growth myself and putting it in the equation as $v_{t0}$, maybe proper fitting would handle that?